# Access Comparing Two Records from Today and Yesterday

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table called Past_Wires that looks like this (partly)

```
Eff_Date | Portfolio | Balance
6/13/2017  0JR         10000
6/13/2017  S25         10000
6/14/2017  0JR         0
6/14/2017  S25         20000
```

I want to run a query that compares the balances of each portfolio to the previous date's balance (hopefully yesterday's date) and return the difference. I am pretty sure this needs to be done in VBA (which I can do) and cannot be done in a query itself, but wanted to see if anyone had ideas.

Comment: I see the Vba code taking the Max Date and comparing it to the Max Date - 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` the table to itself.

Something like

```
SELECT a.Balance as oldBalance, b.Balance as newBalance, a.Eff_Date as OldDate, b.Eff_Date as NewDate
FROM Past_Wires as a
INNER JOIN Past_Wires as b ON a.Portfolio = b.Portfolio AND a.Eff_Date<b.Eff_Date
```

You could also use `DateDiff('d',a.Eff_Date,b.Eff_Date) = 1` in the `WHERE` clause to only compare subsequent days with each other.

Comment: would there be any way in this join to do the balance addition?

Comment: nvm that's basic SQL to add. Sorry